# JPA Query involving Joda Intervals

Tags: mysql, jpa, find, criteria

So I'm using the Play Framework (1.2.5) to develop an application. But I'm having a little trouble with retrieving some specific data.

I have two classes: Event and Site. An Event takes place over a time period (defined as a Joda Interval) and contains several sites. Each Site has a location (defined with a lat and lng). What I want to do is get a list of Sites that are involved in an Event during a specific time period (and possibly within a map boundary).

How exactly would I go about doing this query? I've tried using JPA's CriteriaBuilder and even writing out the query myself, but I haven't a clue about how to tackle the time periods.

Event Model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "event")
public class Event extends GenericModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;
    @Columns(columns = {
        @Column(name = "start"),
        @Column(name = "end")})
    @Type(type = "org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentInterval")
    public Interval eventPeriod;
    public String title;
    @ManyToMany
    public List<Site> sites = new ArrayList<Site>();
}
```

Site Model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "site")
public class Site extends Model {
    @Column(name = "akey", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public String key;
    public Double latitude;
    public Double longitude;
}
```

SQL used to create tables in DB

```
CREATE  TABLE event (
    id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    start DATETIME NOT NULL ,
    end DATETIME NOT NULL ,
    title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE  TABLE site (
    id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    akey VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
    latitude DOUBLE NOT NULL ,
    longitude DOUBLE NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (id) ,
);

CREATE  TABLE event_site (
    event_id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    sites_id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    KEY FKevent_id (event_id),
    KEY FKsites_id (sites_id)
);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Persistent Interval adds two attributes; 'start' and 'end' to your variable that you can access during querying. As an example in your case you would want

```
from Event
where :targetDate between eventPeriod.start and evenPeriod.end
```

They are mentioned in the java doc but I found I had to read the code to work out how to use them.
http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/contrib/hibernate/apidocs/org/joda/time/contrib/hibernate/PersistentInterval.html